# Solving differential equation $ t^{2}x''-2x=t^{3}$ using variation of parameters formula

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

I tried myself so many times and still got a wrong answer.

Note: $f(t) = t^3$

I got the solution for homogeneous equation: $x_{h}(t) = c_{1}t^{2}+c_{2}t^{-1}$

so that $x_{1}(t) = t^{2}$ and $x_{2}(t) = t^{-1}$

Wronskian $W(t)$ = $x_{1}(t)x_{2}'(t)-x_{1}'(t)x_{2}(t)$ = $-t^2t^{-2}-2tt^{-1}$ = $-3$

$c_{1}(t)= -\int \frac{x_{2}(t)f(t)}{W(t)}dt =\frac{1}{9}t^3$

$c_{2}(t)= \int \frac{x_{1}(t)f(t)}{W(t)}dt = -\frac{1}{18}t^6$

$x_{p}(t) = c_{1}(t)x_{1}(t)+c_{2}(t)x_{2}(t) = \frac{1}{18}t^5$

So $x(t) = x_{h}(t) + x_{p}(x) = c_{1}t^{2}+c_{2}t^{-1}+\frac{1}{18}t^5$

However, the answer should be $x(t) = c_{1}t^{2}+c_{2}t^{-1}+\frac{1}{4}t^3$

I am so confused right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are asked to solve this using Variation of Parameters (VoP), given:

$$\tag 1 t^2 x''- 2 x = t^3$$

**Step 1**

The homogeneous solution to $(1)$, is:

$$\tag 2 t^2 x''-2 x =0 $$

This yields:

$$x_h = \dfrac{c_1}{t} + c_2 t^2$$

**Step 2**

Now, making use of VoP, set: $x_1 = \dfrac{1}{t}$ and $x_2 = t^2$ from $x_h$ and $f = t$ from $(1)$.

Calculate the Wronskian of $x_1$ and $x_2$, yielding $W\left(\dfrac{1}{t}, t^2\right) = 3$.

Using VoP:

$$u_1 = \int \dfrac{-x_2 f}{W \left(\dfrac{1}{t}, t^2\right)} dt = \int \dfrac{-t^3}{3} dt = -\dfrac{t^4}{12}$$

$$u_2 = \int \dfrac{x_1 f}{W \left(\dfrac{1}{t}, t^2\right)} dt = \int \dfrac{1}{3} dt = \frac{t}{3}$$

Now, $x_p$ is given by:

$$x_p = x_1 u_1 + x_2 u_2 = \dfrac{t^3}{4}$$

**Step 3**

Our final solution is given by:

$$x(t) = x_h(t) + x_p(t)$$

Comment: Thank you very much for answering! I have one question. Why $f(t) = t$, not $t^3$?

Comment: By definition, see the blue box at: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/VariationofParameters.aspx, you want $x''(t)$ by itself in other words.